# "entry point could not be located" when running program on Windows

Tags: rust

I wrote a program to parse some filenames in Rust using the standard [Regex](http://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/index.html) crate. The program runs fine on Linux, but when I tried to compile and run it on Windows, I get some kind of DLL error. I don't really understand what is going on with this, but it's all I have to go on.

[image: error message]

This is the compiler version that I'm using:

```
F:\Coding\rust-shutterstock-deduper\target (master)
λ rustc --version
rustc 1.0.0-nightly (3ef8ff1f8 2015-02-12 00:38:24 +0000)
```

This is the program that I'm trying to run:

```
#![feature(plugin)]

#![plugin(regex_macros)]
extern crate regex_macros;
extern crate regex;

fn main() {
        let x = regex!(".*");
}
```

And my `Cargo.toml` file:

```
[package]

name = "my_package"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = ["Nate Mara <natemara@gmail.com>"]

[dependencies]
regex = "0.1.14"
regex_macros = "0.1.8"
```

Are there compiler flags that I should be passing in, or do I need to run this in a special way, or... what am I doing wrong here? I'm just running with `cargo run`

Comment: I was able to compile and run this just fine using `rustc 1.0.0-nightly (3ef8ff1f8 2015-02-12 00:38:24 +0000)` on a 32-bit Windows 7 VM. You should reduce your program, creating a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Once you have reduced the size of code, you should also include your `Cargo.toml`, how you are building, and exactly how you are launching your program.

Comment: @Shepmaster Just edited to show those details. I'm trying to build on win8 x64, with 32-bit rustc and 32-bit gcc.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you. What is the purpose of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `#[no_link]` to your code:

```
#![plugin(regex_macros)]
#[no_link]
extern crate regex_macros;
```

Right now, plugins are crates, which means they get linked in. The [regex_macros crate](https://github.com/rust-lang/regex/issues/16) should tell you to add `no_link`, but this is a temporary workaround for a [Rust issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20769). However, it looks like this is in the [process](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/21043) of being [fixed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/22026).